# How to join replace based on a condition and then how to get a count please?

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~Variable_1, ~ Variable_2, ~Variable_3,
  "A", "C", "F",
  NA, NA, "E",
  "C", "A", NA,
  "F", "C", "A"
)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 A          C          F         
2 NA         NA         E         
3 C          A          NA        
4 F          C          A
```

How I could create a condition to join together any of the columns where the rows have `A` and `C` present in any of the variables?

And how to change the name of the combination of `A-C` or `C-A` to, for example `X`?

Also does anyone know how I could get a count of the **number of rows where F appears?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do:

#### Question 1:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Variable_1:Variable_3, ~case_when(. == "A" | . == "C" ~ .), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(x, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = '-')  

Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3 x    
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 A          C          F          "A-C"
2 NA         NA         E          ""   
3 C          A          NA         "C-A"
4 F          C          A          "C-A"
```

#### Question 2:

```
library(dplyr)

count <- df %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . == "F")) %>% 
  nrow()

count

[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Do you know how I would get the count of A-C and C-A. I tried using | but had no luck

Comment: If there are more than 1 'A' or 'C' in some rows, you will get something like "A-C-A" or "C-C-A".

Comment: @DarrenTsai you are right. Obviously this is a solution for the provided data frame and it seems that it fulfills the needs of the OP. :-)

Comment: @Randomname just add `count(x)` as a new line to the existing code.